# Redirect to the partial view from where user gets auto-logged out

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm currently implementing auto logout in my MVC4 project. But, whenever a user logs back in on auto logout from a partial view, there's a page loaded with CSS stripped html as a main page and no functionality works.

Is there any straight forward implementation that I'm missing here?

Added Details:

I'm using form authentication as
    `<forms name="authCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" path="/" timeout="30" />`

For some reason, with this implementation, there's no redirect to login page happening after auto logout. So, I wrote javascript function to read this value and redirect user to login page. This workaround is breaking some flow which is requiring more workarounds. Following is my current client side redirect code.

```
<script>
        var timeout = '@FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds';    
        var wintimeout;

        function SetWinTimeout() {
            wintimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
                debugger
                alert("Your session has timed out. You'll be redirected to login page.");
                window.location = '@FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl' + '?ReturnUrl=' + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
            }, timeout); // In millisecods
        }

        $('body').click(function () {
            //when user clicks remove timeout and reset it
            window.clearTimeout(wintimeout);
            SetWinTimeout();
        });
        SetWinTimeout();
    </script>
```

Comment: This will likely be that you have an action that returns only the partial. Once logged in the action will return a redirect. You just need to make sure that the routing is set up correcly so that the URLs always return the full view and not just a partial.

Comment: A parital view won't have layout. Layout usually contains the css and scripts. Does your auto logout have the css and scripts?

Comment: Does the redirect page use a Layout?

Comment: @DavidEsteves I'm trying to return ActionResult instead of PartialViewResult. This helps with the purpose but I'm handling redirect from clientside. Now, I need to have return url so that page redirects to atleast main page of the the partial view.

Comment: @Jasen It's the partial view which is not loading properly after logging back in post auto-logout. Do I need to have layout in partial view?

Comment: @Mr.B No the partial view doesn't have a layout.

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you are trying to do, but if you just want to drop the current user session and redirect to the login page, the following code will do it.

Comment: Added more details in my question.

Comment: Does the alert ever get called?

Comment: Also does the redirect ever occur?  I suspect a JS error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87208/discussion-between-kinjaldave-and-mr-b).